# Woocommerce customer can create a order and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any way to create a payment page that has 2 fields, one area for the customer to put in the total to pay, and one area for the customer to add notes like what the order is. Then it goes to the checkout page for them to pay.

```
function custom_cart_shortcode(){
    global $woocommerce, $product;

    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url(); 

    $custom_cart_input = '<form action="'.$checkout_ur.'" method="post">

            <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="product-price"> Amount to Pay(USD): </td>
                        <td class="product-price"> <input class="wc_input_price" id="_order_total" name="_order_total" placeholder="0" value="" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="product-price">Order Note :</td>
                        <td class="product-subtotal"><textarea type="text" name="order_note" id="add_order_note" class="input-text" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>';
            $cart_button = '<p class="buttons"><a href="'.$checkout_url.'" type="submit" class="button checkout">Checkout</a></p></form>';
    $cart_controller = do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' );
    $new_cart = $custom_cart_input.$cart_button.$cart_controller;
    return $new_cart;
}
add_shortcode('custom_cart', 'custom_cart_shortcode');
```

is it possible ? please give me suggestion. or idea how I can go ahead ?

[image]

Comment: It would probably be easier to create the order in the admin and send the customer the invoice from there. See the WooCommerce docs for [adding an order manually](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-orders/#section-2)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you want a developer's specific help, then you should hire a developer. Otherwise, I answer questions on SO when I have time and am interested in a question as I have **already** explained the other time that you tagged me asking for help. Please stop tagging me in other people's questions to ask for help. Especially, when I've already provided a perfectly viable solution in my previous comment.